# error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=10

Tags: java, android-studio

I apologize for my lack of experience, but I've been staring at my screen for multiple hours trying to make this work, and I just can't. I know there's a simple solution that I can't see, but I either haven't found it, or I couldn't make sense of what I found. I wouldn't be surprised if a seasoned coder looked at this code and threw up a little bit inside so feel free to correct the heck out of me if you've got the time.

Okay, so my goal was to create a speed reading app because I thought it would be relatively simple, but still enough to make me learn. I have created an app that makes text appear, and cycles through the words, but once it gets the end it throws a "unfortunately, has stopped" in my face and returns to the MainActivity.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

**My code:**


      package com.example.android.speedread;
            import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.view.Window;
            import android.view.WindowManager;
            import android.widget.Button;
            import android.widget.TextView;

            public class ReadActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_read);


                }

                public void onClickButtonStart(View view) {

                    //removes button once its clicked
                    Button btn_startReading = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_startReading);
                    btn_startReading.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    //gets content from an EditText from another class
                    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                    if (extras != null) {
                        String s = extras.getString("userInput");
                        final String[] words = s.split("\\s+");

                        //starts Thread for displaying said text
                        Thread t = new Thread() {

                            int currentWordNumber;

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                TextView tv_onScreenWord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_onScreenWord);

                                                //This is where I get an error, and I understand why I'm getting the error,
                                                //but I'm just not sure how to deal with it.
                                                tv_onScreenWord.setText(words[currentWordNumber = currentWordNumber + 1]);
                                            }
                                        });

                                    }
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                                }

                            }

                        };

                        t.start();

                    }

                }
            }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
**My layout code:**
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context="com.example.android.speedread1.ReadActivity"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryWhite">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="100sp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:id="@+id/tv_onScreenWord"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Start"
                    android:id="@+id/btn_startReading"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:onClick="onClickButtonStart"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryWhite" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `currentWordNumber = currentWordNumber + 1`. `currentWordNumber` isn't set initially, so it defaults to the integer default of 0.  Then on each access, you're iterating it **before accessing** it, so you're getting `words[1]` for the first run, `words[2]` for the second run, ..., `words[words.length]` for the last run (causing the exception).

Use `currentWordNumber++` instead of `currentWordNumber = currentWordNumber + 1`. `currentWordNumber`.  In general, `x++` means that x is used, and then incremented (so, on the first iteration, it would give you words[0], and then get incremented from 0 to 1).  On the other side, what you're doing is equivalent to `++x`; you're setting the value **before** using it (so, on the first iterations, you increment from 0 to 1, and then get words[1]).

Alternatively, remove `currentWordNumber` and use `words[i]` instead.  What does this external index add?

Answer (score 0):

When you evaluate the expression `currentWordNumber = currentWordNumber + 1`, it evaluates to 1, not 0 on the first iteration, so the second, not the first word is processed.  It adds 1 on each iteration, so on the last iteration, the expression will be equal to `words.length`, which is one past the end of the array.

If you change the expression to `currentWordNumber++`, the value used to look up a value in the array is the value of `currentWordNumber` BEFORE it is incremented, so on the first iteration, the array index will be 0, and `currentWordNumber` will then be incremented to 1.  On the second iteration, the array index will be 1, and `currentWordNumber` will be incremented to 2 and so on.